# Azure URL is not working for the new CNAME entry

Tags: dns, cloud, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager

Recently we have created a new CNAME entry for the internal react website which is deployed in Azure. It has been pointed to traffic manager since we are deploying in two regions. After the CNAME entry is create, the URL throws 404 error. We have already configured the entry access restriction to all internal users. Appreciate if anyone can help to identify the issue.

Comment: Could you show the result of querying the new DNS. eg, `nslookup www.example.com`?

Comment: Yes it shows up with name,address and aliases.In aliases, it shows up traffic manager url  and app services URL. I cannot post the result due to security reasons. Do i need to check anything in specific?

Answer (score 1):

For the error, you could add the new CNAME subdomain to your app service---custom domains---add custom domain as the picture displaying steps 1-5. After you validate the subdomain and add the subdomain into the custom domains, you should access the subdomain URL via the traffic manager. Read [this blog](https://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/sspencer/2015/01/15/setting-custom-domain-for-traffic-manager-and-azure-websites/) for more details.

[image]

In addition, only Web Apps at the **Standard** SKU or above are eligible for use with Traffic Manager. Attempts to add a Web App of a lower SKU fail. Read [Azure web apps as the endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-endpoint-types#web-apps-as-endpoints).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the information.I have tried to add the custom domain by entering CNAME domain and selecting CNAME as Hostname record type, in app service, but "Add Custom Domain" is not getting enabled.

Comment: What do you mean "Add Custom Domain" is not getting enabled.? Any screenshots? Do you use SKU standard or above price tier for your app service?

Comment: I use Standard for app service. Add Custom Domain button is disable even after entring the values

Comment: Could you directly access the traffic manager URL to get your endpoints? The Monitor status of the endpoint is online?

Comment: I update my picture. Let me know which step do you stuck on?

Comment: Hi,Some issue in Azure side,so we are working with the team.Thanks for your help.

Comment: well, If your original question has been fixed, please share the solution here.